# Excel equations using months

Tags: excel

I am trying to come up with an equation.  Here is what I am trying to do.  I am trying to get a running total by multiplying a monthly rate for renting something that will at all times keep a running total at all times.  Monthly rate x month started = Running total.  Keep in mind there doesn't need to be a total based on the number of days owned on a month (Not to be pro-rated in other words.)  Something like if it cost $100 a month in January. Then by July 1st you would owe $600.  On June 15th for example you would still only owe $500 because the month hasn't ended.  In other words the running total would only show completed month totals.  Maybe I don't have the best knowledge of excel but I am ok at the equations.  The problem is from using months instead of simply multiplying numbers.   Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this would be to have dates in one column like '01/Jan/2013', '01/Feb/2013' etc. then the next column would have the formula of `= 100 + CellAbove`

Answer (score 0):

Use DateDif or Month

= DATEDIF ( start_date , end_date , "interval")

so to calc the months from January to July  using Months try this

=DateDif("1/11/2013", '6/1/2013"), "M") will yield 4

=DateDif("1/01/2013", '6/1/2013"), "M") will yield 5

=Month("1/11/2013") - MONTH("6/1/2013") will yield -5

=Month("6/1/2013") - MONTH("1/1/2013") will yield 5

Substitute the References in place of my Direct Dates. i.e.

A1 = "6/1/2013"

A2 = "1/1/2013"

A3 = "=MONTH(A1)-Month(A2)"

See what works for you!

Steve

Comment: I see what you are doing Steve and thanks.  What I didn't mention is (I am doing 10 different rental equipment at once, on one page so I only have so much room.  I am trying to see if possible to do it by entering the beginning date ex. 1/1/13 have another place for monthly rate and have a separate place for running total.  That way I can pull up the worksheets in the excel saved file at any day and see the total owed for each piece of equipment rented based only on completed months. I hope my explanation is clear enough. If I pulled up today something rented since May 1st would show may-july